# What is the relative scale of the My Little Pony universe?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

Quite simply, how do the people(?) and things in the MLP universe compare to real-world equivalents? Are the ponies the size of people, or RL ponies? Or smaller/bigger? How about things like trees or houses?

Comment: They have to be littler than something, or their whole life is a lie.

Comment: TODO: mention http://goldengriffiness.deviantart.com/journal/Canon-Pony-Sizes-Confirmed-607794351

Comment: @Oldcat I always assymed that they are littler than the usual ponies, but, of course, there's some room for interpretation...

Comment: MLP is DEFINITELY on topic here as it is fantasy. If talking and flying ponies isn't a fantasy concept I want to live where you're living, or smoke what you're smoking!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Hearth's Warming Eve, Twilight said, "I spy an 8 foot candy cane." Scootaloo was standing next to it. Comparing Scootaloo and the candy cane together, we can estimate that she is about 3 feet tall. Adult ponies are slightly taller, I estimate 4 feet. Because the ponies are in the same proportion to houses, trees, etc. in their world as we are in ours, it can be assumed that these things were shrunk down for proportion.

[image: Scootaloo licking the candy cane in the aforementioned "I spy" scene of S2 E11]

Comment: Unless of course, a pony foot isn't the same as a human foot.

Comment: @Keen Of course they aren't, pony feet are hooves :)

Comment: I completely agree with the 8-foot-candy-cane scale. If the ponies are, in fact, ponies, this scale makes sense, as any equine under around 5 feet is considered a pony. Interestingly, Luna and Celestia would then qualify as horses, being around six or seven feet to the head.

Comment: Alicorns don't count! Also horses aren't even measured with feet, they're measured by hands!

Comment: @Rob: A pony is any breed of horse which, when fully grown, is between 9.5 and 14.3hh (hands high). 4ft is 12hh. While not an answer to the OP's question, my personal take puts the MLP characters around 10hh (~3.33ft), which would make them _little_ ponies ;) (Also: MLP ponies have a concept of "horses," distinct from "ponies." Flim and Flam sing "any horse can make a claim and any pony can do the same," and in the current season, the Crusaders sing about having "hearts as strong as horses.")

Comment: @Rob: Don't be ridiculous! Horses don't have hands!

Comment: @BrianS Great. Now you got the Flim Flam song stuck in my head again ;)

Answer (score 28):

As of *Pinkie Pride*, we have another scale to go on; Cheese Sandwich stands against a height chart.

[image: Cheese Sandwich Height Chart]

There is one major, glaring flaw with the calculations above: They measure from the top of a pony's head to the ground. This is understandable, as it's what you do when measuring a human's height, and we're humans (most of us...); unfortunately, that technique doesn't work for quadrupeds, who can move their head up and down a considerable distance, and do so frequently (especially the two characters measured in this image!)

Instead, you need to measure from the animal's back to the ground. In the case of horses, the standard is to measure from their withers, a bony ridge between their shoulder blades, right at the base of the animal's neck. (In fact, this is the standard for measuring dogs, too, so we could use it to get Winona's height!) Unfortunately, MLP ponies aren't rendered with withers, so we have to estimate. The point on the back where the neck and back meet is good.

Using the above screenshots, this puts Cheese Sandwich at 2.9ft and Pinkie at 2.04ft. In horse measurement terms, that's 8.28 and 6.19 hands high, respectively. (1hh = 4in, 0.1hh = 1in)

In the real world, a "pony" is a horse breed which measures less than 14.2hh when fully grown, and more than 8.2-9.2hh. (Less than that is a "miniature horse," but the range is because of differing classification by differing breed registries.) With some margin for error<sup>1</sup>, that puts the MLP characters on the low end of "pony" height. (Or alternatively, they're *little* ponies! /pun)

I've been asked before why I assume the chart behind Cheese was in feet, instead of another unit or something entirely made-up. I refute the "made-up" argument with the fact that, honestly, there *isn't* that much worldbuilding in MLP, and creating a new unit of measurement would be unnecessary effort. Additionally, it would make the chart completely useless as a frame of reference to the viewer. Using alternative units, however, is argued against by simply presenting the results based on those other units:

- Meters: Pinkie measures ~20hh. (Approximately 1in shorter than **the** tallest horse in the world.)
- Decimeters: Pinkie measures ~2hh, 1/4 the minimum height for a pony. (This is less than 1ft tall.)
- Inches, Centimeters: Even *Big Mac* is less than 1hh. (We're now on the scale of the blind bag toys.)

---

1. Sources of error:

- Finding Cheese's withers in the first image is difficult, since he's facing the camera.
- The withers are actually slightly higher than the rest of a horse's back, but MLP ponies don't have one.
- Comparing the scale on the wall behind Cheese to Cheese's height pixel-by-pixel is inaccurate, since he is not flush against the wall. (This is also a problem when extending this pattern to others, as they need to be the same distance from the camera for it to work correctly.)
- The Mane Six may-or-may-not be fully grown. There are certainly adult characters taller than them.
- The pony-vs-miniature-horse distinction is based on what's normal for the breed, not an individual specimen. Pinkie's measurement above may be under the minimum for "pony," but she might also just be short.

Comment: Is there any indication that the height scale shown on that screencap is measured in feet?

Comment: @b_jonas, there is a section in my answer devoted to exactly that. If the scale is in any other commonly used real-world unit, then the entire world is at a ridiculous scale (in one direction or another), and if it's in an uncommon or made-up unit, then its presence is less than useless.

Comment: 3ft 6in would, incidentally, make a pony approximately the same height as a hobbit :-)

Answer (score 15):

[image: A photo of a person playing a cello is set alongside an image of Octavia playing a cello; the cellos are scaled to be approximately the same size]

Most objects seen in Equestria could be arbitrarily big or small, and the show staff often play fast and loose with measurements. But one thing you can't change the size of is a musical instrument. If Octavia's cello was smaller than a standard cello, it would produce a different sound.

Her un-pony-like stance makes this a bit harder to measure, and Octavia may be smaller than the average earth pony mare, but it appears to suggest a height of about 60cm at the withers, or about 6 hands. This is only a little smaller than the 7 or 8 hands suggested by other methods.

Comment: Well, it could actually be [substantially smaller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHuIswpL4YU)...

Comment: Though appearances may be deceptive...

http://dm29.deviantart.com/art/Lil-Octavia-s-Cello-C-642769443

Comment: It depends on the atmosphere's composition.  If Equestria's air contains a lot of heavy stuff like xenon or sulfur hexafluoride, a small cello will sound pretty deep.  It'd make small-winged flight easier, too.

Comment: @Gaultheria It has been established that pegasi can fly because their pegasi magic. It is also how they control the weather. But your proposal is sound.

Answer (score 13):

In *Equestria Girls*, the human Fluttershy is shown with a rabbit. If you compare it with a scene of pony Fluttershy with her rabbit, Angel, you can conclude that ponies are about half the height of an average teenager.

[image: Fluttershy with Angel Bunny in S1 E7] [image: Fluttershy hands Angel Bunny to human Twilight in Equestria Girls 3: Friendship Games]

Comment: I don't buy it that _Equestria Girls_ are humans.

Answer (score 10):

I found this when browsing around. I hope it helps.

[image: A pony is pulling a train of 3 carts piled with apples; two are circled, a green one labeled "A" and a red one labeled "B." Beside the pony are two stacks of ten each A and B apples. Text on the image reads "This is my own attempt at the Apple Scale, designed to determine the size of the ponies. This shot is at close to 5 minutes into Episode 25, Season 1 ("Party of One"). The two apples used are marked "A"&"B", with each of them stacked 10 high from ground to scalp. If 1 apple = 4 inches, then Applejack's height is around 3ft 4in. By extension, each of the Mane 6 would all be about that tall as well."]

Comment: While you've accurately determined scale between an apple and the height of the Mane 6, it doesn't necessarily translate against anything "real world" as the question asked. You assume that a MLP apple is roughly 4". Why? For all anyone knows, it's actually 20" in Earth-measurements.

Answer (score 10):

In the [official blooper reel](https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x50nflg) for My Little Pony: Equestria Girls – Friendship Games, the following scene appears which provides a pretty clear size comparison between ponies and humans:

[image: Rainbow Dash riding Rainbow Dash]

It is worth noting that the bloopers are non-canon, but they're from about as official of a source as you can get (officially released, fully-animated content from DHX), and I don't see any reason why the animators would alter the relative size of the characters just for this scene. Additionally, this size seems consistent with what has been suggested by the other answers to this question.

Answer (score 9):

It occurs to me that another possible source is [the opening animation to the Equestria Girls movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuyH9Y6jI3E), where the ponies are briefly seen morphing into their human counterparts (only one of whom is actually the same character...)

[image: Equestria Girls side-by-side]

The perspective and movement in this shot make a direct comparison harder, but let's estimate anyway.

Twilight Sparkle has the most normal stance of the six in both frames. Her height as a pony is about 110px to the withers and 225px full height, while her human form is about 350px. If we assuming her human height is 1.62 metres, the average for an American teenage girl, that makes her pony form about 50cm to the withers, or 5 hands; and her full height as a pony 1.04 metres, or 3 feet 5 inches.

This is smaller than the other estimates. There are several unproven assumptions in this method though. I still favour the cello method.

Answer (score 7):

darthbobcat [attempted to answer this in a 2011 forum post](https://forums.giantitp.com/showsinglepost.php?p=11385768&postcount=596), and found that they are quite small as real world ponies go.  He based his measurement on the size of cows.

[image: Applejack talking to Daisy Jo the cow, screenshot from S1 E4]

Let me quote parts of that post (bolding mine).

> Since the dawn of Friendship is Magic, we have known that our little ponies are, in fact, little. But how little? The problem has been what to use as a baseline. Trees don't have a set height. Items in their houses would, of course, be scaled to their size. Dog breeds, bunny breeds and cat breeds vary in size.
>
> And then I realized my point of comparison. The **cows** that Applejack deflected from trampling Ponyville **have the coloring of Holstein cattle. That means we know the breed!**
>
> According to Wikipedia, a Holstein cow, at maturity, is about 58 inches (147 cm) at the shoulder.
>
> Where you measure the cow at the hip is roughly equivalent to the height of its front hoof to the top of its back. And Holsteins have a fairly flat back.
>
> Applejack is [...] **27.6 inches (70 cm)**
>
> Now to put this in perspective. The Shetland Pony is the smallest horse breed in the world,
>
> Rounding up, **Applejack is the size of the smallest individuals OF THE SMALLEST PONY BREED IN THE WORLD.**
>
> So the answer is: they are very little ponies indeed.

[image: Pinkie Pie talking to Daisy Jo the cow, screenshot from S2 E18]

The two illustrations are screenshots from S1 E4 and S2 E18 respectively.

Answer (score 5):

Another one from the Equestria Girls movie, where Twilight puts her hand through the portal and her arm is transformed. Good luck getting an accurate scale from it, though.

[image: Twilight stands outside the portal with just her left arm stuck in; through the portal we see her arm becoming a leg with a hoof]

Answer (score 3):

There was a video (since removed from YouTube) that finds the actual height of the ponies. They're about four feet tall.

Basically, it used the "8 foot candy cane" theory. It used pixel ratios and cross-multiplication to find Scootaloo's height (75.79cm), then it showed a different image with both Rarity and Scootaloo in it, and it used the same strategy to find Rarity's height (120.24cm, or about 4 feet).

Comment: Can you post a quick summary of their reasoning in case the video gets axed by Google off CopyrightViolationTube? :)

Comment: Basically, it uses the "8 foot candy cane" theory. It uses pixel ratios and cross-multiplication to find Scootaloo's height (75.79cm), then it shows a different image with both Rarity and Scootaloo in it, and it uses the same strategy to find Rarity's height (120.24cm, or about 4 feet).

Comment: Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3X6p9NuBSgo

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - Which then happened.

Answer (score 3):

So we now have 3 strong hints at the roughly 120cm (4ft) size, including the head. Assuming this is correct, Equestria has insanely high gravity - more than the gravity on Jupiter!

There's a video investigating that which I tried to debunk but ended up mostly confirming, [see here](https://shnatsel.blogspot.com/2014/04/and-now-for-something-completely.html) for both the original video and my (hopefully more credible) calculations.

So we've calculated Equestrian gravity assuming 4ft size; **but what if we try the reverse - assume Earth-like gravity (g=9.8m/s^2) and try to calculate size?**

Using my [previous gravity research](https://shnatsel.blogspot.com/2014/04/and-now-for-something-completely.html) and assuming Earth-like gravity, Spike's spectacular jump into the lava was merely 3 meters high! The highest point of the jump measures 16 Spikes, so one Spike is 300/16 = ~18cm, or 7". **That puts mane 6 at just 25 cm or at about 10" tall, including the head.**

Unfortunately I can't tell if it's the ponies that are really small or if it's the gravity in their world is so insanely enormous. But either way, the "human transported to Equestria" fanfics are not credible: the human would either be crushed by the enormous gravity, or turn out to be just too damn huge compared to the ponies.

*If the latter is true, perhaps the human should try to hang out with dragons instead? They're more their size!*

Comment: Megan, Molly, and Danny were human, but perhaps then Discord attacked, causing the inconsistent laws of nature and forcing the pony princesses to control the day/night cycle.

Answer (score 3):

I cross-referenced the data and compared 5 different sources. They all converge around 3' to 1 meter:

Answer (score 0):

I like to think this.

- I think a regular mare is 4 feet 5 inches, more or less because not everyone is the same height.
- I think a filly (the cmc for example) is about a foot shorter, at around 3 feet 5 inches, a little more or less possibly.
- Fancy pants, Luna, Fleur de lis, Sassy saddles, Cadence, and other ponies like that are probably around 5 feet.
- I think celestia would be about 7 feet including her horn.

I also made a picture and journal explaining the height of wings and horns. If you want to read the whole thing [here is the link](https://www.deviantart.com/happy-note/journal/How-big-are-horns-and-wings-598244288). This shows how big wings and horns are, while [this one](https://www.deviantart.com/happy-note/art/Mlp-Scale-579205652) shows how big the ponies themselves are.

Just to shorten it, a filly's horn is 5-7 inches, an adult's around 9 inches, Fleur, Luna, Cadence, Fancy pants etc. have a horn of around 14-16 inches, while Celestia's is 21 inches. For the wings, a filly's is a little less than a foot at about 10 inches. For an adult pony, wings are 27 inches or 2.25 feet. Luna and Cadence's wings are around 33 inches (almost 3 feet). And Celestia's wings are a whopping 45 inches, which is almost four feet.

Hope this helped!

Comment: You've started your calculations with "*let's assume all the filly pegasi we see are 3 feet 6 inches*". Why did you pick that? Why shouldn't we assume that they're all 600ft tall?

Comment: @Richard: That'd be interesting. Instead of physically moving clouds around, pegasi would simply spawn tornadoes all the time instead.

Answer (score -1):

I just saw this yesterday.

> [image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: We generally frown on answers that are just links to external content. Ideally, you should explain (or just sum up) the most relevant points from the linked content. At the very least, you should re-host the image on our servers in case the link dies.

Comment: Phantom42 is right and if you want more info and an easy badge at the same time simply take the [tour] ;)

Answer (score -1):

This is some impressive math. I have a hard time figuring out how big ponies are myself. As a cartoonist I go by how many heads tall. The mares and stallions all have started out using the same basic body shape, three heads tall. They have regular deer as seen in Filly Vanilli. The doe is four heads tall. Fluttershy's forehead brushes the doe's chin. Compare that height to the whitetail deer around hunting season that range from 62 to 87 inches.

These are the notes I scribbled here.
[click here for image, it was a little big](https://humblemarty.deviantart.com/art/How-I-figure-out-Sizes-in-MLP-Friendship-is-magic-695640446?ga_submit_new=10%3A1501382703)

I compared it to this website.
http://www.deertrail.us/minnesotawildlife/minnesotawildlife/whitetaildeer.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Perhaps it is intended to be a comment on another post.

Answer (score -4):

Alright so here's my theory. It hinges on one assumption: That the environment is of roughly the same scale as an RL environment. From here, one can figure one of two sizes are correct:

- Objects such as houses and trains are depicted as strictly to-scale, at which point ponies are roughly RL pony size (around human height, 6+ feet long, etc.)
- Objects such as houses and trains are slightly chibi-fied for the cartoon format, at which point ponies are slightly smaller than people (~4ish feet tall, slightly longer, maybe 10 inches wide)

Comment: Any reason for downvotes? :(

Comment: I'd suspect it was because this answer doesn't really answer anything; it presents two equally likely theories. A good answer is conclusive.

Comment: Why would little ponies build huge houses for themselves? They seem happy enough to not overcompensate.

Answer (score -4):

The average MLP pony is about the size of a large domestic cat when aged to adulthood. Foals around the age of the CMC are about half that size. Stallions are slightly taller than mares, but no significant difference, to me at least. Now, we are going to look at Celestia's height. Celestia is two times the size of an average pony if I'm not mistaking it.

If what I'm saying is true, than even if I'm counting her horn, Princess Celestia is half the height of the average adult human being.

I know you are telling me 'ponies are bigger than that, deal with it', and stuff like 'but ponies are not cat-sized'. And yes, I know of Equestria girls bloopers and all that, and bloopers are not canon. And between us, I do not think that the 'humans' of Equestria Girls are not humans at all.

It's okay to have your own opinions, but don't pick on me because of my opinion.

Comment: It's certainly okay for you to have your opinions, but not for you to post them as answers. Unless you can make a case for them using information from the show.